# ROS Master Communciation Error - BeagleboneBlack

Tags: ros, master, ros-master-uri, beagleboneblack, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our setup: Laptop running Ubuntu, serially connected to a BeagleboneBlack running Debian Wheezy.
From the laptop, SSH-ing serially into the BBB is successful. Roscore is running on latop.

However, when any ROS command is attempted while SSHed into the beaglebone, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
```

On the beaglebone:

```
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://localhost:11311
```

where localhost is 192.168.0.105

On the laptop:

```
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://localhost:11311
```

where localhost is once again 192.168.0.105 (the IP address of the laptop)

To debug, we try running `roswtf` on the BBB and receive the following error:

```
root@beaglebone:~/twf_catkin_ws# roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: rosinstall -- bloom -- rosrelease --

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/root/twf_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory:
 * /root/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

Being new to ROS, we are confused as to the relationship between the PythonPath and how the BBB communicates with master. I realize these two could be unrelated. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220120/ros-master-communciation-error---beagleboneblack/) by [rking1020](https://answers.ros.org/users/24952/rking1020/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here's](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) the wiki page that explains how to setup multiple machines for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0